# Updating the notification when app is killed by swiping while using intent service android

Tags: android, notifications, intentservice, android-intentservice

I am using **IntentService** and updating notification showing progress. I want to update notification when the app being uploaded and manually killed by swiping. I tried to update it in **onTaskRemoved** by changing service **stopWithTask** attribute to "false" method but it doesn't work. Can anyone suggest me with a solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If an application is killed its notifications just disappear from the taskbar ...

Comment: @Tonteria24 its not disappearing